# Visitor pattern for const and nonconst versions of a tree

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

I am stuck with a code duplication issue, regarding the visitor pattern for a tree. The current situation is as follows: I have a tree, consisting of two different node classes, i.e. leafs and non-leafs. In addition I have two visitor base classes that look very alike except that one visits const trees and the other non-const trees. The actual actions the concrete visitors have to do are independent of the node's concrete types. I'll give a short example:

```
class Visitor;
class ConstVisitor;

class Node {
public:
  virtual void accept(Visitor&) = 0;
  virtual void accept(ConstVisitor&) const = 0;
};

class Leaf : public Node {
  virtual void accept(Visitor& v)        {v.visitLeaf(*this);}
  virtual void accept(ConstVisitor& cv)  {cv.visitLeaf(*this);}
};

class CompoundNode : public Node {
public:
  vector<Node*> getChildren() const;
  virtual void accept(Visitor& v)        {v.visitCompoundNode(*this);}
  virtual void accept(ConstVisitor& cv)  {cv.visitCompoundNode(*this);}
};

class Visitor {
protected:
  virtual void processNode(Node& node) = 0;
public:
  void visitLeaf(Leaf& leaf) {
    processNode(leaf);
  }
  void visitCompoundNode(CompoundNode& cNode) {
    processNode(cNode);
    auto children = cNode.getChildren();
    for (auto child : children)
      child->accept(this);
  }
};

class ConstVisitor {
protected:
  virtual void processNode(Node const& node) = 0;
public:
  void visitLeaf(Leaf const& leaf) {
    processNode(leaf);
  }
  void visitCompoundNode(CompoundNode const& cNode) {
    processNode(cNode);
    auto children = cNode.getChildren();
    for (auto child : children)
      child->accept(this);
  }
};
```

Concrete visitor classes inherit either from `Visitor` or from `ConstVisitor`, depending on whether their `processNode` method has to alter the nodes visited or not.

You see, there is lots of code duplication between the two visitors, and since I will have to implement another traversal strategy, also for both const and nonconst nodes, I want to avoid that duplication. Are there any possibilities to extract the duplicate code, preferably without using `const_cast` all over the place?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could define a `TVisitor` class template as done below:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Node;
class CompoundNode;
class Leaf;

template<bool isNonConstVisitor>
class TVisitor
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<isNonConstVisitor, 
        Node, Node const>::type node_type;

    typedef typename std::conditional<isNonConstVisitor, 
        CompoundNode, CompoundNode const>::type compound_node_type;

    typedef typename std::conditional<isNonConstVisitor, 
        Leaf, Leaf const>::type leaf_node_type;

protected:

    virtual void processNode(node_type& node) = 0;

public:

    void visitLeaf(leaf_node_type& leaf) { processNode(leaf); }

    void visitCompoundNode(compound_node_type& cNode) {
        processNode(cNode);
        auto children = cNode.getChildren();
        for (auto child : children) { child->accept(*this); }
    }
};
```

And then use `Visitor` and `ConstVisitor` as type aliases for corresponding instantiations of that class template:

```
typedef TVisitor<true> Visitor;
typedef TVisitor<false> ConstVisitor;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a fast and clean solution. I hope my colleagues don't hate templates too much ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use templates:

```
template<typename NodeType,
         typename CompoundNodeType,
         typename LeafType>
class BaseVisitor {
protected:
    virtual void processNode(NodeType& node) = 0;
public:
    void visitLeaf(LeafType& leaf) {
        processNode(leaf);
    }
    void visitCompoundNode(CompoundNodeType& cNode) {
        processNode(cNode);
        auto children = cNode.getChildren();
        for (auto child : children)
        child->accept(this);
    }
};

class Visitor: public BaseVisitor<Node, CompoundNode, Leaf> {
};

class ConstVisitor: public BaseVisitor<const Node, const CompoundNode, const Leaf> {
};
```